# In ssrs report if the address field has a null value, it's generating an empty space

Tags: reporting-services

I have to generate a ssrs report to people to have paid the items.

1) `iif(Fields!ccpaid.Value ="Y" ,Fields!address1.Value , Fields!address2.Value)`

2) `iif(Fields!ccpaid.Value ="N" ,Fields!address1.Value , Fields!address3.Value)`

1 is working fine. But in 2 one some time address3 will have null values. 
So it will generate an empty space. I need to remove the space.

output as of now
     ABC
     Address1

```
 Address4
```

I need as 
      ABC
     Address1
     Address4

`iif(Fields!ccpaid.Value ="N" ,Fields!address1.Value , Fields!address3.Value).`

In the row visibility I tried 
`=iif(Fields!address1.Value is nothing or Fields!address3.Value ="", true, false)`

`iif(Fields!ccpaid.Value ="N" ,Fields!address1.Value , Fields!address3.Value).`

In the row visibility I tried 
`=iif(Fields!address1.Value is nothing or Fields!address3.Value ="", true, false)`

I need to remove the white space in address if its null value

output as of now
     ABC
     Address1

```
 Address4
```

I need as 
      ABC
     Address1
     Address4

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 expression. and your field `Fields!address3.Value` does retun null sometimes.
It can also be that your Field `Fields!address1.Value` and `Fields!address2.Value` can also be null.

What I did below is check if your Field does return some value, if it does not then blank without space else field value. This shall help you.
You do not need Row visibility.

1)

```
IIF(Fields!ccpaid.Value ="Y" ,IIF(Isnothing(Fields!address1.Value),'',Fields!address1.Value),
IIF(Isnothing(Fields!address2.Value),'',Fields!address2.Value))
```

2)

```
IIF(Fields!ccpaid.Value ="N" ,IIF(Isnothing(Fields!address1.Value),'',Fields!address1.Value),
IIF(Isnothing(Fields!address3.Value),'',Fields!address3.Value))
```